# Audited wrong date-time in DB

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, audit

I use `@Audited` annotation in Spring to have auditing about my update, create etc. on my db.

But I obtain  on my database, a date-time with 2 hour less than real time, for example, I created a object and the I saved it, I have as create date-time: 2014-08-04 12:0 but I created it at 14:00.

This is my Auditor class, that every class audited extend:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractAudit implements Auditable<String, Long>, Serializable {

    @Version
    private int version;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(updatable=false)
    private String createdBy;

    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE_TIME)
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(updatable=false)
    private DateTime createdDate;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE_TIME)
    @JsonIgnore
    private DateTime lastModifiedDate;

        //getter and setter method
}
```

How can I fix it?? 
Have I add some configuration on my project or on my server (Tomcat 7) ?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried asking the OS that is running the App what time it is? If linux the you can fire the "date" command

Comment: yes, the date on my server is correct..

Comment: If you where to set a breakpoint in your code and print out the date, what timezone would it print?  Does that match what timezone the OS is set for?  How about the DB?  If the time is off two hours, I'd suspect one of your systems thinks it's the wrong timezone, and thus making some incorrect calculation.

Comment: The date-time that I get debbugging my web app is correct.. I have no idea..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set this property in your jpa provider settings:

```
<prop key="jadira.usertype.databaseZone">jvm</prop>
```

Hope this helps.

Regards